# Concept of big endian and little endian

Tags: c++, c, storage, unions

In union all elements refer to the same slot of memory. Thus if we consider int as 2 bytes ,then it contains the value in binary as 00000001 00000000(256). Since the size of char is 1 byte, so the first half(1 byte) should be allocated with 00000001 and the second half should be allocated with 00000000. But why does the following code print `256 0 1` rather than `256 1 0`?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {

        union a{
               int i;
               char ch[10];
               };

        union a u;
        u.i=256;
        printf("%d,%d,%d",u.i,u.ch[0],u.ch[1]);
        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: This just means that you run it on Little Endian machine.

Comment: Because you're on a [*little-endian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) system (like all x86 systems are)?

Comment: As `u.i` is the active member reading from any other element of the union is undefined behaviour.  Some compilers implement extension(s) to allow this you need to check you have enabled them. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

Comment: @RichardCritten The C standard allows type-punning via a union (although C++ doesn't), as well as accessing any type using a `char *`.

Comment: @RichardCritten That depends on language. In C type-punning using unions is allowed. In C++ it's *not* allowed. So the should really specify what language is *really* used.

Comment: C and C++ are two *very* different languages. Especially the behavior is different for using union members. So please edit you question to pick *one* of the languages.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Show me a C++ compiler where it doesn't work when all the types affected are C-like types and I'll show you a C++ compiler that can't use X Windows. It's not allowed in C++ due to the difficulty of defining its behavior when the advanced features get in play.

Comment: @Joshua Just because it seemingly works in some cases doesn't mean it's okay to do something the specification explicitly mentions as UB.

Comment: you have just written an endianness detector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little-endian* machine.

The bytes of i are laid out with the low byte first.

If you had a big-endian machine the expected output would not have been "256 1 0" unless `sizeof(int)` were 2. I don't think you have a 16 bit processor. On the more likely `sizeof(int)` of 4, you would have the output of "256 0 0". Try this program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

    union a{
           int i;
           char ch[sizeof(int)];
           };

    union a u;
    u.i=256;
    printf("%d", u.i);
    for (int b = 0; b < sizeof(int); ++b)
        printf(",%d", (int)(unsigned char)(u.ch[b]));
    printf("\n");
    return 0;

}
```

This will show you all the bytes of `u.i` in order as your processor lays them out.

*Assuming you're not on a PDP. You don't want to know about PDP.

Comment: Nice reference to the good ol' PDP-11.  Takes me waaaaay back.

Comment: Endianess may be better visualized using hexadecimal.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Yeah but OP likes decimal.